# Maintaining windows placement when switching between computers

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, kvm-switch

I have KVM switch for MBP (Mac OS X 10.7.2) and PC (Windows 7 64-bit), sharing wireless keyboard, mouse, and dual DVI monitors.  For the second monitor, I have a DVI to USB adapter connected directly to the KVM box.  Everything works perfectly, I hot-key between my MBP and PC throughout the day. The only issue I have is when I switch between computers, whatever windows I have open are always moved to the primary monitor when I switch back.  Very annoying in an otherwise perfect world.  Does anyone know of a way to maintain the windows placement on both PC and MBP when switching?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the KVM switch not maintaining full-time DDC communication between the connected systems and the sharing monitor. There's two ways to solve it:

1. Add an EDID emulator between each connected PC/system and the KVM switch.
2. Find KVM switch that supports full time EDID/DDC communication.